# warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion ArrayList <String> Java

Tags: java, warnings

Tras compilar mi proyecto **Clean and build**, he encontrado que tengo bastantes **warnings** algunos de tipo conversión de datos. El proyecto me funciona correctamente pero querría limpiar los **warnings**.

Algunos de ellos:

```
linea 68: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        dnis = Conexiones.cargar_dni();
  required: ArrayList<String>
  found:    ArrayList
linea 74: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
            jComboBox_DNIs.addItem("Seleccione un DNI...");
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
linea 78: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
                jComboBox_DNIs.addItem(i.next());
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
linea 84: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            ArrayList <String> ciudades = Conexiones.cargar_ciudad();
  required: ArrayList<String>
  found:    ArrayList
```

**¿Por qué me dice que se esperaba un ArrayList pero encontró un ArrayList sin declarar de qué tipo es cuando sí lo he declarado?**

Es muestro el código de esas líneas:

```
        ArrayList<String> dnis = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Cargamos los valores de la función "cargar_dni" de Conexiones.java en el arrayList "dni".
        dnis = Conexiones.cargar_dni();

        if(!dnis.isEmpty()){
            //Creamos un iterator para recorrer el ArrayList.
            Iterator<String> i = dnis.iterator();
            //Dato inicial del jComboBox_DNIs
            jComboBox_DNIs.addItem("Seleccione un DNI...");
            //Recorremos el iterator "i".
            while(i.hasNext()){
                //Añadimos a los items cada dni.
                jComboBox_DNIs.addItem(i.next());
            }

            //Creamos una variable de la clase TextAutoCompleter.
            TextAutoCompleter tac = new TextAutoCompleter(textfield_ciudad);
            //Creamos un arrayList de ciudades y le cargamos las ciudades.
            ArrayList <String> ciudades = Conexiones.cargar_ciudad();
            //Recorremos el arraylist y añadimos al "tac" cada una de las ciudades.
            for(String ciudad: ciudades){
                tac.addItem(ciudad);
            }
```

**Código cargar_dni:**

```
        public static ArrayList cargar_dni() {
            ArrayList<String> dnis = new ArrayList<String>();
            String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
            Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
            Statement stm;
            ResultSet rs;
            try {
                //Consulta para sacar todos los DNIs de la tabla "clientes".
                stm = c.createStatement();
                String consulta_dnis = "SELECT dni FROM clientes ORDER BY dni ASC";
                rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_dnis);
                //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS DNIs: Mostramos todos los DNIs de la tabla 'clientes'.");
                int i = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String dni = rs.getString("dni");
                    dnis.add(dni);
                    i++;
                }
                //System.out.println(dnis);
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Ha habido un error.");
            }     
            return dnis;
        }
```

**Código cargar_ciudad:**

```
public static ArrayList cargar_ciudad() {
    ArrayList<String> ciudades = new ArrayList<String>();
    String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
    Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
    Statement stm;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        //Consulta para sacar todas las ciudades de la tabla "clientes".
        stm = c.createStatement();
        String consulta_ciudades = "SELECT DISTINCT ciudad FROM clientes";
        rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_ciudades);
        //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS teléfonos: Mostramos todas las ciudades de la tabla 'clientes'.");
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            String ciudad = rs.getString("ciudad");
            ciudades.add(ciudad);
            i++;
        }
        //System.out.println(ciudades);
        c.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Ha habido un error.");
    }     
    return ciudades;
}
```

Deduzco que el código está bien programado pero, ¿cómo se pueden resolver esos warnings?

Comment: Porque tus funciones están definidas para  retornar un `ArrayList` sin especificar de qué tipo son los elementos del `ArrayList`. En tu caso deberían ser `public static ArrayList<String> cargar_ciudad()` y `public static ArrayList<String> cargar_dni()`

Comment: @SuperG280 ¿Por qué la línea 78 y 84 no se me resuelve la advertencia? Ya declaré el private JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(); pero sigue apareciéndome ese fallo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linea 68: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        dnis = Conexiones.cargar_dni();
  required: ArrayList
  found:    ArrayList

- El método cargar_dni, devuelve un ArrayList. Para quitar el warning, define el tipo de elementos del ArrayList .

`public static ArrayList<String> cargar_dni()`

---

linea 84: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            ArrayList  ciudades = Conexiones.cargar_ciudad();
  required: ArrayList
  found:    ArrayList

- El método cargar_ciudad, devuelve un ArrayList. Para quitar el warning, define el tipo de elementos del ArrayList

`public static ArrayList<String> cargar_ciudad()`

---

linea 74: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
            jComboBox_DNIs.addItem("Seleccione un DNI...");
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox

linea 78: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
                jComboBox_DNIs.addItem(i.next());
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox

- ¿Tienes definido el tipo de datos que utiliza tu Combobox? No incluyes tu declaración, pero creo que ese warning se solucionaría añadiendo su tipo:

  `JComboBox<String> jComboBox_DNIs`

Comment: He añadido en Customize Code del jComboBox el tipo de dato <String> inicializándolo y no se resuelve el warning. Lo he declarado en el Customize debido a que es código Java Swing generado por la interfaz.

Comment: Y añadiéndolo en el customize, solucionado?

Comment: No, sigue saliendome el error. warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(E) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
                jComboBox_DNIs.addItem(i.next());
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox